# Hiding an element and sliding it doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, hide, sliding

I want to achieve sliding and I have this jquery

```
$(function() {
    **$('#tableschema').find("td[colspan=2]").hide();**
    $('#tableschema').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") ==2) {
           $target.closest("tr").slideToggle("fast");
            $target.closest("tr").prev().find("td:first").html("+");
        } else {
           $target.closest("tr").next().slideToggle("fast");            
           if ($target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html() == "+")
                $target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html("-");
else
                $target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html("+");                
        }                    
    });
});
```

But since I am hiding the column span in the first place I am not able to achieve sliding . Your help on this is very much appreciated.
tableschema - Table ID
If I remove the hide , its working good . But there is an extra row that is appended due to "p" tag which I have used inside tr and td.

Comment: Your bigger problem is attempting to slide a `td`. Animating table elements rarely works very well

Comment: can you provide jsFiddle. then it will be easy for us to help you.

Comment: If you need to slide a `td` you'll need to put a `div` inside it and slide that.